# При удалении с ON DELETE SET NULL на таблице с внешними связями на саму себя удаляются так же связанные записи

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
--1
CREATE TABLE department (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100));
--2
CREATE TABLE employee (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
department_id INT,
chief_id INT,
name VARCHAR(100),
salary INT,
FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES department (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (chief_id) REFERENCES employee (id) ON DELETE SET NULL);
```

Вторая имеет зависимость на саму себя.

Далее я пытаюсь удалить одну запись, на которую ссылаются 3 другие записи, но разными командами.

***1ая команда*** прямо указывает через `id`, что удалять:

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE id=17;
```

Все записи, у которых было `chief_id=17` теперь имеют `chief_id=NULL`, так как установлено ON DELETE SET NULL.

***2ая команда*** использует подзапросы, но удаляет всё ТУ ЖЕ САМУЮ запись c `id=17`:

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE department_id = (SELECT id FROM department WHERE name = 'managment') AND chief_id IS NULL);
```

Но при это автоматически удаляются так же и все записи с `chief_id=17`, то есть которые ссылались на удалённую запись!

Я вообще не понимаю, как это может работать. У меня же установлено `ON DELETE SET NULL`. Но работает только для 1-ой команды почему-то.

---

UPD: Добавляю примеры.

`department`:

```
╔════╦════════════╗
║ id ║    name    ║
╠════╬════════════╣
║  2 ║ management ║
╚════╩════════════╝
```

`employee`:

```
╔══╦════╦═══════════════╦══════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║  ║ id ║ department_id ║ chief_id ║  name   ║ salary ║
╠══╬════╬═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║  ║  5 ║             2 ║          ║ Rita    ║   5000 ║
║  ║  6 ║             2 ║        5 ║ John    ║   1400 ║
║  ║  7 ║             2 ║        5 ║ Fatima  ║    100 ║
║  ║  8 ║             2 ║        5 ║ Chester ║   2000 ║
║  ║    ║               ║          ║         ║        ║
╚══╩════╩═══════════════╩══════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

Теперь если выполнить команду:

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE id=5;
```

То результат будет такой:

```
╔══╦════╦═══════════════╦══════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║  ║ id ║ department_id ║ chief_id ║  name   ║ salary ║
╠══╬════╬═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║  ║  8 ║             2 ║          ║ Chester ║   2000 ║
║  ║  7 ║             2 ║          ║ Fatima  ║    100 ║
║  ║  6 ║             2 ║          ║ John    ║   1400 ║
║  ║    ║               ║          ║         ║        ║
╚══╩════╩═══════════════╩══════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

А если вместо нее выполнить команду (ссылается на ту же запись):

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE department_id = (SELECT id FROM department WHERE name = 'management') AND chief_id IS NULL;
```

Результат:

```
╔══╦════╦═══════════════╦══════════╦══════╦════════╗
║  ║ id ║ department_id ║ chief_id ║ name ║ salary ║
╠══╬════╬═══════════════╬══════════╬══════╬════════╣
║  ║    ║               ║          ║      ║        ║
╚══╩════╩═══════════════╩══════════╩══════╩════════╝
```

Удалено всё!

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как 2-ая команда _удаляет всё ТУ ЖЕ САМУЮ запись c id=17_, если эта запись была удалена 1-ой командой? Добавте пример исходных данных, вывод запросов и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Разумеется, я делаю это через START TRANSACTION. И просто пытаюсь удалить первой командой, а потом второй. И результат разный.

Comment: Добавил примеры. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Данные всегда публикуте как текст,  а не картинки! Я добавил на [фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ea65ce274bfde6ed6e8511b7eec6639) парочку записей. Вас интересует, как я понял, почему поведение отличается от других СУБД. Насколько помню, в MySQL проверка FK, в отличие от стандарта SQL, выполняется сразу же до выполнения основной операции. По стандарту, проверка должнa быть defered, т.е. после выполнения перед commit. Поэтому  
и разница.

Comment: Понятно, что ничего не понятно. Я на фиддле потестил ваш код в разных СУБД: у всех разный результат. Кто-то удаляет всё, кто-то как надо работает. Где я могу подробнее почитать? Мне ваш ответ ни о чём не говорит, честно говоря.

Comment: Ну я ещё не отвечал, это только комментарий. А что осталось непонятным? Например, что вы ожидаете, если проверка на FK будет выполнена до удаления? Другими словами, событие `on delete` будет запущено до того, как  основная команда delete приступит собственно к удалению.

Comment: Я ожидаю, что зависимые записи получат NULL, как и указано. И я всё ещё не понял, почему удаление одной и той же записи влечёт разные последствия для остальных записей: при удалении через ID всё работает как надо и устанавливает NULL, а в  другом случае удаляет все записи как было бы при установке ON DELETE CASCADE. И вообще  ON DELETE CASCADE нельзя установить, если FK ссылается на свою таблицу, как здесь.

Comment: _Я ожидаю, что зависимые записи получат NULL_, хорошо, т.е. в нашем примере, все записи имеют теперь chief_id=NULL. В условии на удаление стоит chief_id is NULL. Это значит не одну запись, а все записи удовлетворяющие условию. Так сколько записей будет удалено в результате? Я ожидаю, что все.

Comment: Кажется я понял. То бишь он до удаления сделает всем NULL по событию ON DELETE, а потом будет удалять по запросу, под который уже подойдут все записи. Женская логика, конечно, у СУБД. Но я рад, что разобрался. Спасибо вам!